# PNG to NSImage and back causes jaggies near transparency

Tags: cocoa, opengl, png, nsimage

I'm resizing some PNG files from within a Cocoa app. The files are eventually loaded as OpenGL textures by another app, and a poorly-written shader is applied, which at one point, does the following:

```
texColor = mix(constant,vec4(texColor.rgb/texColor.a,texColor.a),texColor.a);
```

Dividing by alpha is a bad idea, and the solution is to ensure that the RGB components of texColor in that step never go above 1. **However!** For curiosity's sake:

The original PNGs (created in GIMP), surprisingly work fine, and resized versions created with GIMP work fine as well. However, resizing the files using the code below causes the textures to have jaggies near any transparent pixels, even if `percent` is `1.0`. Any idea what it is that I'm unwittingly changing about these images that suddenly causes the shader's bug to present itself?

```
NSImage* originalImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[currentFile regularFileContents]];
NSSize newSize = NSMakeSize([originalImage size].width * percent, [originalImage size].height * percent);
NSImage* resizedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:newSize];
[resizedImage lockFocus];
[originalImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)
                 fromRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,[originalImage size].width, [originalImage size].height)
                operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
[resizedImage unlockFocus];

NSBitmapImageRep* bits = [[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:[resizedImage CGImageForProposedRect:nil context:nil hints:nil]] autorelease];
NSData* data = [bits representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
NSFileWrapper* newFile = [[[NSFileWrapper alloc] initRegularFileWithContents:data] autorelease];

[newFile setPreferredFilename:currentFilename];
[folder removeFileWrapper:currentFile];
[folder addFileWrapper:newFile];

[originalImage release];
[resizedImage release];
```

Comment: Can you post an example image before and after?

Comment: It turns out it may have been a shader issue in the loading app--at one point, the fragment shader divides by the alpha component of the texture, which, near fully transparent areas, caused issues for obvious reasons. I'll leave the question, because I'm still very confused as to what about *this* resizing code brings the problem out, when GIMP's PNGs won't.

Answer (score 0):

I typically set image interpolation to high when doing these kinds of resizing operations. This may be your issue.

```
[resizedImage lockFocus];
[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setImageInterpolation:NSImageInterpolationHigh];
[originalImage drawInRect:...]
[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
[resizedImage unlockFocus];
```

---

Another thing to make sure you're doing, though it may not help (see below):

```
[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setShouldAntialias:YES];
```

This may not fix it because you can't anti-alias without knowing the target background. But it still might help. If this is the problem (that you can't anti-alias this soon), you may have to composite this resizing at the point that you're ready to draw the final image.

Comment: Thanks; it didn't solve the jaggies, but it seems wise to keep it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What is the DPI of your source PNG? You are creating the second image by assuming that the original image's `size` is in pixels, but `size` is in *points*.

Suppose you have an image that is 450 pixels by 100 pixels, with DPI of 300.  That image is, in real world units, 1 1/2 inches x 1/3 inches.

Now, points in Cocoa are nominally 1/72 of an inch.  The size of the image in points is 108 x 24.

If you then create a new image based on that size, there's no DPI specified, so the assumption is one pixel per point. You're creating a much smaller image, which means that fine features are going to have to be approximated more coarsely.

You will have better luck if you pick one of the image reps of the original image and use its `pixelsWide` and `pixelsHigh` values.  When you do this, however, the new image will have a different real world size than the original. In my example, the original was 1 1/2 x 1/3 inches. The new image will have the same pixel dimensions (450 x 100) but at 72 dpi, so it will be 6.25 x 1.39 inches. To fix this, you'll need to set the `size` of the new bitmap rep in points to the `size` of the original in points.

Comment: Aren't *all* the values in that code in points, thus making the resolution irrelevant?

Comment: The original image can have a size in points which differs from its size in pixels, due to a DPI different than 72. The new image is created with a size in points, but doesn't have a size in pixels or DPI separately specified. So, its DPI is 72. It will match the original in size (in points) but may not match in pixels, which is the observed problem.

Comment: Ah, yes--forgot about `resizedImage`'s missing resolution. Thanks. Unfortunately, this didn't fix it (my original PNGs were 72 DPI anyway).